# How to track opportunity closed as won outside the form,Like from a view

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I open a webresource (HTML) when an opportunity is closed as won.
This is triggered only by clicking on the button in the opportunity form.
I use the following code to achieve the same:

```
 function FrmOnSave(prmContext) {
 var lclSaveMode;
 if (prmContext != null && prmContext.getEventArgs() != null) {
 lclSaveMode = prmContext.getEventArgs().getSaveMode();
 if(lclSaveMode==5)
 {
   window.openStdWin(url,"myWindow");
 }
```

However this does not get triggered when the opportunity is closed from the "Open Opportunity" view. Is there a way to achieve the same? Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do here, would be to hide the existing close button, add a new button which looks the same and does all the same things but also opens that window.

Comment: Hi,Would try as you have mentioned, however i see another problem, i close the above window automatically on certain conditions. Seems to work fine on internet explorer however on outlook it throws an alert box stating the following "The web page you are viewing is trying to close the window". How to avoid this alert from popping up?

Comment: Is that just a feature of IE?

Comment: I think so. As i have mentioned earlier i have the script on Save of the form and it opens a window(HTML) web resource. I close the window using the following function window.close() on certain condition. The window closes automatically without any alert on IE but when working through Outlook it throws an alert.Is there a way to avoid the same? I tried Xrm.page.ui.close(), but that did not close the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug using IE (F12) to see which javascript function is being called on your case, or what is actually happening.

@James Wood answer is a good advice though, it is the safest way to achieve what you want.